# What's wrong with iTunes Framework and Xcode on 10.14?

Tags: xcode, frameworks, itunes

everything worked without issues, now with MacOS Mojave i get this in Xcode:

```
#import <iTunesLibrary/ITLibrary.h>
```

Error: File not found

Already tried reading the Framework, ensured the search paths are set, but nothing changes...
The funny part is, Xcode knows about the framework, because it suggests it while typing the Command, but on compile, it fails, cannot create App Updates anymore due this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself, the new Xcode broke all the Framework Search Paths, had to remove all entries and fix other Frameworks by hand, but it works now